# why my code is unable to handle large array input(>10000)?

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior, subscript-operator

```
int n;//input size of array
cin >> n;
vector <int> a(n);
vector <int> in;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];//input array elements
if (n == 1) {
    cout << "1" << "\n";
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)//to get longest incresing subsequence in the array
{
    int flag = 0, j = i;

    while (j < n && a[j] >= a[j - 1] ) {
        j++;
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        in.push_back(j - i + 1);
        i = j;
    }
}

int maxval = in[0]; //to get maximum sized element from in 
for (int i = 1; i < in.size(); i++)
    if (in[i] > maxval)
        maxval = in[i];
cout << maxval << "\n";
```

I tried the same code for values < 10000 it's working fine...i've replaced all int's by long long int's then also it's showing vector subscript out of range error...

Sample input :

```
10

49532 49472 49426 49362 49324 49247 49165 49162 49108 49093
```

i'm expecting 0 but it shows "vector subscript out of range"

Comment: Make this mistake often enough and you'll learn that `<=` in looping code is always a code-smell.

Comment: *i'm expecting 0 but it shows "vector subscript out of range"* -- What is the issue understanding this error?  The error is self-explanatory.

Comment: Aside: the final loop can be replaced by [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) (found in `<algorithm>`)

Comment: '_i'm expecting 0 but it shows "vector subscript out of range"_' So, get a debugger, and use it to determine which subscript is invalid, where, and then figure out why and fix it.

Comment: _"i'm expecting 0"_ Explain why.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sure? There is a `j < n` condition.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, that is true, not easy to read.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why this is getting upvoted.  The error should be obvious in terms of what it is stating.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica...i haven't mentioned it explicitly but thanks for pointing it out it should be "1" actually...(for longest increasing sequence) !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason of the problem is this statement

```
int maxval = in[0];//to get maximum sized element from in
```

The vector `in` is empty when this input is used

```
10

49532 49472 49426 49362 49324 49247 49165 49162 49108 49093
```

So you may not use the subscript operator.

You could write for example

```
int maxval = in.empty() ? 0 : in[0];
```

Comment: alternatively, they could change `if (flag == 1) { in.push_back(j - i + 1); i = j; }` to `in.push_back(j - i); i = j;`

Answer (score 2):

Fix this:

```
int maxval = in.size()? in[0]:0;
```

the vector class operator checks the index is between lower and upper limit of array which will be (0 -> size-1)

MSVC lib:

```
    _NODISCARD _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos) noexcept { // strengthened
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    }
```

the problem is that the in.push_back never get called then the size is zero.

so in[0] call operator will throw exception index out range.

Comment: An answer should explain what was wrong and how it resolves that. Anyway, this just repeats what Vlad already wrote, in a less clear way. (I didn't downvote, fwiw.)

Comment: "_vector class operator checks the index_" `operator[]` does not have to check anything. The fact that it sometimes does in debug builds produced by some compilers should not be relied upon. If an index might be out of bounds at runtime and is not controllable, the user must use `.at()` to ensure that the index is checked and an exception thrown if invalid. `operator[]` makes no guarantee and is free to turn your entire program into undefined behaviour if it receives an invalid index, so only users who are confident what they are doing should use it.

Comment: you are right but he is getting exception and here is the operator definition:

Comment: _NODISCARD _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos) noexcept { // strengthened
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    }

Comment: so he is building debug build

Comment: It doesn't matter what your stdlib implementation does. `operator[]` is not required by the Standard to check bounds, and assuming it will is an irresponsible recipe for disaster.